# AngularJS - How to disable directory browsing/listing when rendering views with Http web server

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, httpserver

My RESTful MEAN application has a node.js server for back end and HTTP-server in the front end. Following is the project structure:

[image: My MEAN Restful project structure]

When i run My Directory/app/HTTP-server from the console and do the browsing its displaying the page as follows with directory listing/browsing:

[image: Directory Browsing/Lising]

Once i click on views the pages are rendering. Following is my app.js:

```
'use strict';

var app = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute', 'authControllers', 'authServices']);
var authControllers = angular.module('authControllers', []);
var authServices = angular.module('authServices', []);

var options = {};
options.api = {};
//dev URL
options.api.base_url = "http://localhost:3000";

app.config(['$locationProvider', '$routeProvider',
function($location, $routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.
  when('/', {
    templateUrl: 'partials/home.html',
    controller: 'authCtrl'
  }).
  when('/login', {
    templateUrl: 'partials/signin.html',
    controller: 'authCtrl'
  }).
  when('/register', {
    templateUrl: 'partials/signup.html',
    controller: 'authCtrl'
  }).
  when('/me', {
    templateUrl: 'partials/me.html',
    controller: 'authCtrl'
  }).
  otherwise({
    redirectTo: '/'
  });
}]);
app.config(['$httpProvider', function ($httpProvider) {
  $httpProvider.interceptors.push('TokenInterceptor');
}]);
app.run(function($rootScope, $location, $window, AuthenticationService) {
  $rootScope.$on("$routeChangeStart", function(event, nextRoute, currentRoute) {
    //redirect only if both isAuthenticated is false and no token is set
    if (nextRoute != null && nextRoute.access != null && nextRoute.access.requiredAuthentication
      && !AuthenticationService.isAuthenticated && !$window.sessionStorage.token) {
        $location.path("/login");
      }
    });
  });
```

server.js:

```
var express = require('express'),
jwt = require('express-jwt'),
bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
morgan = require('morgan'),
methodOverride = require('method-override'),
errorHandler = require('express-error-handler'),
tokenManager = require('./server/config/token_manager'),
secret = require('./server/config/secret'),
http = require('http'),
path = require('path');

var app = module.exports = express();

app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);    
app.use(morgan('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(methodOverride());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'app')));

var routes = require('./server/routes');
routes.users = require('./server/routes/users.js');
var env = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';

// development only
if (env === 'development') {
  app.use(errorHandler());
}

// production only
if (env === 'production') {
  // TODO
}

app.all('*', function(req, res, next) {
  res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost');
  res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
  res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, DELETE, PUT');
  res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Authorization');
  if ('OPTIONS' == req.method) return res.send(200);
  next();
});

/*
Login
*/
app.post('/login', routes.users.login);
app.post('/user/register', routes.users.register);
app.get('/me', routes.users.me);

/*
Logout
*/
app.get('/logout', jwt({secret: secret.secretToken}), routes.users.logout);

process.on('uncaughtException', function(err) {
    console.log(err);
});

/**
* Start Server
*/
http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function () {
  console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
});
```

What needs to be done to disable this directory listing/browsing or to simply render my view on http://localhost:8080/ ?

Comment: Can you show your server.js file contents?

Comment: @Salem: Modified the question with server.js code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `server.js` change

```
express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'app'));
```

with

```
express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'app'), {index: false});
```

Comment: Actually, Its still showing the directory browsing after the changes